# Is there assign a dunder method a custom operator?

Tags: python, operators, customization, user-defined

So I was wondering is it possible to make a new dunder method that has its own operator? 
Something like this:

```py
class test:
  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name
     pass
  def __user__(self, times):
    return(self.name*times)

---------- 
Run
----------

Python 3.7.1 Shell

>>> a = test('stackoverflow')
>>> a -!? 1
'stackoverflow'
>>>
```

Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT: ** Thank you @user2357112-supports-Monica and @Mad-Physicist for explaining to me what I wanted to do is impossible (without recompiling Python that is...) and how to do my original example.

Comment: There's already a method for `@`. It's `__matmul__`, because `@` is intended for matrix multiplication.

Comment: You can't add your own operator, but you can implement the defined ones as you choose. What's your specific question?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with a custom dunder method?

Comment: Well it was to make a custom operator but now I know I cant do that